# Simple Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, ef-fluent-api

If have the following table structures

```
Key            Site           Building         Person              Grade

Primary key    SiteId         BuildingId       PersonId            GradeId
Foreign key                   SiteId           BuildingId
                                               GradeId
```

Knowing the SiteId, I am looking to obtain a list of Person objects which have a set grade.

I am using the uof and repository patterns and the code used to pull out the data is as follows:

```
var site = unitOfWork.Repository<Site>()
                  .Query(si => si.SiteId == siteId)
                  .Select()
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
List<Person> person = Person.Where(p => p.Site.SiteId == 99 
                  && p.Site.Building.person.Grade == 3);
```

but I cannot see site from person or grade objects in intellisence.

I have tried to include the tables, but again, intellisence does not allow me to dig deeper then the next object, so

```
var site = unitOfWork.Repository<Site>()
                  .Query(si => si.SiteId == siteId)
                  .Include(si => si.Building)
                  .Include(si => si.Building.Person) ..... not visible
                  .Select()
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

What do i need to change to either enable me to:

- pull back the extra table objects in the initial query
- traverse the objects using intellisence
- using existing code to pull a person object

Comment: There is no direct relation between Person and Site that is why it is not mapped in the EF and it is not shown in the intellisense. You should try accessing Site for a person via building. Like `person.Building.SiteId` also you can directly access Grad by doing `person.GradId`. Can you share your EF Model and Mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var person = Person.Where(p => p.Building.SiteId == 99 && p.GradeId == 3).ToList();
```